# Tensorflow strange CPU usage

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

my problem is with Tensorflow and the usage of the CPU. 
My System:

- CPU => AMD FX 8320 (8 Cores á 3,5ghz) and 8 Threads
- Grafik => GTX 970
- RAM => 16Gb and i belive ddr3 2600

I want to run a A3C algorithm for Starcraft 2 (pysc2) on my pc what works fine but the usage of the cpu ist somewhat strange.

If i start the algorithm with 4 Workers i get something about 150k Steps in 1h
and all cpu's are used about 25-30%

If i start the same algorithm with 8 Workers i get something about 120k Steps in 1h and all cpu's are used about 25-30%

If i now start the algorithm with 4 workers twice i get each 150k steps 1h and the cpu usage is 60-70%

Why cant i start the algorithm with 8 Workers, get the double amount of steps in 1H and the cpu is used to 70%?